# Regex capturing any text between

Tags: regex

I'm trying to capture text (any text) that falls between some kind of delimiter with word boundaries on each end, like so:

This is not the text. ##This is the text I want to capture.## This is also not the text. ##But I would like to capture this, too##.

I thought this would be easy with regex like this

```
\b([#]{2})(.*)(\1)\b
```

This doesn't produce a match and I can't figure why.

Note, I would also like to avoid capturing the text between the first '##' and the last '##', capturing both sections with all the text in between.

In other words I don't want one of the matches to be:

> ##This is the text I want to capture.## This is also not the text. ##But I would like to capture this, too##

Comment: You might want to make your expression non-greedy: `##(.+?)##`

Comment: `\b` - word boundary, zero-length match between `\w` and `\W`. However, `#` and `space` are both non-word characters (`\W`) so `\b` will not match between `space` and `#`.

Answer (score 2):

[georg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3494774/georg) and [Ulugbek Umirov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1803777/ulugbek-umirov) posted the perfect answer on this question as comment. I repeat the expression here with an explanation mainly to give the question an answer and therefore remove it from the list of unanswered questions.

`##\b(.+?)##` searches for a string

- starting and ending with `##` and
- with a word character at beginning and
- having 1 or more characters between.

Because of the parentheses the string found between `##` is marked for backreference.

The question mark `?` after the `+` multiplier changes the matching behavior from greedy to non greedy. The greedy expression `.+` matches everything from first `##` to last `##` whereas the non greedy expression `.+?` matches just everything from first `##` to next `##`.

`\b` means word boundary and therefore the first character after `##` must be a word character (letter, digit or underscore).

The matching behavior of `.` depends on a flag. The dot can match any character including line terminating characters, or any character except line terminating characters. Line terminating characters are carriage return (= \r = CR) and line feed (= newline = \n = LF).

If matching everything between two delimiter strings should be independent on matching behavior of the dot, it is better to use the regular expression `##\b([\w\W]+?)##` like  [Ulugbek Umirov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1803777/ulugbek-umirov) suggested as `\w` matches any word character and `\W` matches any non word character. Both in a character class definition matches therefore always any character including CR and LF.

It would be also possible to use `##\b([\s\S]+?)##` where `\s` matches any whitespace character and `\S` matches any non whitespace character resulting with both in a character class definition in matching any character including CR and LF, too.

Further it would be possible to use `##(\w[\s\S]*?)##` or `##\w([\w\W]*?)##` or `##(\w.*?)##` all resulting in the same matching behavior as all other expressions above, if the matching behavor for dot is any character including CR+LF.

Last, if the used regular expression engine supports lookbehind and lookahead, it would be also possible to match only the string between `##` without matching the delimiters by using for example the regular expression `(?<=##)\b[\w\W]+?(?=##)` which makes the need of a marking group unnecessary. `(?<=##)` is a positive lookbehind expression and `(?=##)` is a positive lookahead expression both for the string `##`.